# data.frame to array of JSON arrays in R

Tags: arrays, json, r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R with two columns, for example:

```
df = data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4), y=c(5, 6, 7, 8))
```

I need to write an R script to convert this data.frame to a JSON array of arrays, like this:

```
[[1, 5],[2, 6],[3, 7],[4, 8]]
```

How do I convert my data frame to a JSON array of rows in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `toJSON` from `library(jsonlite)`

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(setNames(df, NULL))
#[[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[4,8]]
```